# Extend seach range for all sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this [script](https://abnaa.notion.site/Google-Script-cd2ea22e25f140149699c92759fd6d5f) and an input form to search a Google spreadsheet, this script has a range of one sheet,i.e. Data , but I need to extend my range to all sheets in the same spreadsheet, any ideas?

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate()
    .setTitle("WebApp: Search By Password")
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var concat = formObject.searchtext + formObject.searchtext2;
  var result = "";
  if (concat) {//Execute if form passes search text
    result = search(concat);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS ;
function search(searchtext) {
  var spreadsheetId = ' '; //** CHANGE !!!!
  var sheetName = "Data"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ar = [];
  data.forEach(function (f) {
    if (~[f[8]].indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push([f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7]]);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Please put the contents of the script in your post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search for a text from all sheets of a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this by modifying the script in your question.

In this case, I would like to propose modifying the function `search` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function search(searchtext) {
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()
    .flatMap(s =>
      s
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues()
        .filter(r => r[8] && r[8].includes(searchtext))
        .map(([,,c,d,e,f,g,h]) => [c,d,e,f,g,h])
    );
}
```

#### Note:

- When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks again, excuse my ignorance, I did change the search function but the script with a new deployment stopped running! I should mention that I will send the link to my students which means I need to assign a fixed ID of my Google spreadsheet instead of activeSpreadsheet, I also don't know how to use getSheets parameter! Do I have to provide sheets names within () ?

Comment: @ahsan Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?